# run node safe prevent RPC hack!

Tags: rpc

I was running a node on my vps and my coinbase account was hacked. could anyone tell me what would be the default command to start geth on port 8545. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not unlock account on rpc provider node. If you are mining from same node, use separate nodes for mining and rpc. Connect them as peers and they will be safe from such attacks.

[How to secure a private chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50475/how-to-secure-a-private-chain/50480#50480)

You can run geth on default setting provided you follow the secure procedures.

Comment: geth --rpc --rpcaddr ('my ip') --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3"
this should be ok? Thank you

Comment: I am trying to launch a smart contract but when i did it last time i unlocked my coinbase account maybe for a few seconds and i got hacked. Maybe i did something wrong last time.

Comment: be aware of the apis you are providing. I don't think all of these apis "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" are necessary. It depends on your task but most of the time "eth,net,web3" are sufficient and secure.

Comment: and for the rest should be ok? thank you

Comment: Yes. You can also try changing default settings such as port numbers. But it does not absolutely secure your rpc.

Comment: if that helped you resolve the issue you can upvote the answer and close it